# Learn Python The Hard Way ex 25

Tags: python, import

I was doing exercise 25 on the book Learn Python The Hard Way. I unfortunately ran into a problem: I can't import the ex25 script in the python shell which is part of the exercise. In fact, I tried importing other exercises (including some from Project Euler and a calculator I made :) ) and I noticed that even if I change the name of the script, importing doesn't work and that the only one who worked was one called "formatter".

Here is the code for the ex25:

```
def break_words (stuff):
    #This function will separate words with spaces
    words = stuff.split(" ")
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    # This function sorts the words 
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_words(words):
    # Prints the first letter of a word by popping it
    word = words.pop(0)
    return word

def print_last_word(words):
    # This function prints the last letter of a word by popping it
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence (sentence):
    # Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted sentence
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    # Prints the first and last words of a sentence
    words = break_words (sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    # Sorts the words the prints the first and last one
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

and here is the "formatter" code:

```
while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

And I have also noticed that, in the book, when the author runs a script he does it like this "python scriptName.py" and I only have to do it like this "python scriptName"

Comment: What is the error you are getting when attempting to import?

Comment: are you receiving an error?  or can you explain what happens when you try to import?

Comment: If your script called `scriptName` but not `scriptName.py` , then you can't import it. But you still can run it in shell via `python scriptName`...

Comment: @KevinGuan you meant "**can't** import it" right?

Comment: @aneroid: Oops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: @devlincarnate The error I get is that there is no module name "ex25".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html):

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix `.py` appended. Within a module, the module's name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`.

So also as I said in comments:

> If your script called `scriptName` but not `scriptName.py`, then you can't import it. But you still can run it in shell via `python scriptName`.

Then rename it and add suffix `.py` would works.

Comment: My script is called "script" and has a .py extension (saved as a python file) is it still going to work?

Comment: @Supermexicano2002: Then it should works fine, what's the error are you getting when you import your script?

Comment: It tells me there is no module named ex25

Comment: @Supermexicano2002: So your script called `ex25.py`, and when you try `import ex25`, it says there's no such module right?

Comment: Nevermind, when I saved the file, instead of naming it "ex25.py", I just named it "ex25" and saved it as a python file. So I just had to rename the script "ex25.py" for it to work, but thanks!

Comment: @Supermexicano2002: Yeah that's what I meant in my answer. However if you think my answer is helpful, please accept it.